# Like button only work when clicked on but cant unlike post object using ajax in Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I'm trying to work Django with ajax to stop the reload of page when a post object is liked by a user, but somehow when the like button is clicked it update the button as liked, but when i click the button to unlike the post doesn't unlike. I'm wondering how i could do it better to stop this malfunction. why does it only toggle to like but doesn't back to unlike ?

```
My likeview 

def Addlike(request,post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        is_liked = False
        if post.like_page_post.filter(id=request.user.id).exists:
            post.like_page_post.remove(request.user)
            is_liked = False
        else:
            post.like_page_post.add(request.user)
            is_liked = True
        return JsonResponse({'is_liked':is_liked,'count_likes':post.like_page_post.all().count()})
```

Ajax function

```
function likeajax($this) {
    var id = $this.attr("id");
    var count_likes = $('#count_likes');
    var like_icon = $('#like_icon');

    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': document.getElementById('csrf').querySelector('input').value},
        method: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'page:like' page.id %}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          
        },
        success: function (data) {
               if(data.is_liked)
                 {
             
                    like_icon.html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="blue" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100" ><path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" /></svg>');
                    count_likes.text(data.likes_count);
                }
                else
                {
                   like_icon.html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="red" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100" ><path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" /></svg>');
                   count_likes.text(data.likes_count);   
                }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Like button HTML

```
 {% if is_liked %}
<a onclick="likeajax($(this)); return false;" id="{{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
<div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600" id="like_icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="blue" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
<path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
  </svg></div>
 <div> Unlike</div>
  </a>
 {% else %}
<a onclick="likeajax($(this)); return false;" id="{{ post.pk }}"  class="flex items-center space-x-2">
<div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600" id="like_icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="red" width="22" height="22"class="dark:text-gray-100">
<path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
</svg></div>
   <div>Like</div></a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* the `.exists()` method, so:

```
if post.like_page_post.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    # …
```

Comment: unfortunately your solution didn't worked after i had added the parenthesis, it still won't toggle to unlike when clicked on @Willem Van Onsem .

Comment: @Godda: you don't change the text in your JavaScript function from like to unlike and vice versa.